# Execute Crontab every 1 and 15 of every month

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, cron

I used to run a script every week, but now I need to run it twice in every month.

My current commands are:

**30 5 * * 1 "command"**

Now I want to run my "command" every 1st and 15th of every month. I do not know what values to put in the third option, the days option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know if you can do it in one line so here in two lines :

- 0 5 1 * * "commande" (1st of every month at 5 am)
- 0 5 15 * * "commande" (15th of every month at 5 am)

**Edit yes you can as pointed by mbieren:**

**0 5 1,15 * * "commande"**

Comment: it is `0 5 1,15 * * "command"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer m.nachury
I think @mbieren is right. I'm gonna test it like that, and see if it works

Comment: yeah but you should mark m.nachury answer as correct.

Comment: mbieren, sad you can't mark a correct comment, I'll edit you in my answer.