# Go-cron expression to trigger on 3rd Thursday of every month

Tags: go, cron, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

How to write a go-cron expression to trigger a run of a job on the 3rd Thursday of every month? This is specific to scheduling pipelines on Kubeflow.

For example: `croniter` library provides the hash symbol for day of the week which allows you to schedule on the nth day of the month. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52203452/airflow-schedule-a-task-to-run-on-the-monday-before-the-15th-of-the-month/52320828#52320828).

Can we do something similar with go-cron?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/robfig/cron?

Comment: Yes i am using that.

Comment: Just visit this page > https://github.com/robfig/cron you will find a way

Answer (score 0):

**answer:**

```
s.cron(0 0 15-21 * 2)
```

I expect the 3 Thuesday to be in the range of the **15-21** day of the month. By limiting in the Thuesday it should run `“At 00:00 on every day-of-month from 15 through 21 and on Tuesday.”`

**further reading:**

[Crons Answer 1 15 days of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45011857/execute-crontab-every-1-and-15-of-every-month)

[Examples of go-cron](https://github.com/go-co-op/gocron#examples)

[The quick and simple editor for cron schedule expressions by Cronitor](https://crontab.guru/)

Comment: ```At 00:00 on every day-of-month from 15 through 21 and on Tuesday.``` Does the cron job do an ```and```  or an ```either/or``` condition check?

Comment: there is only one thuesday on the 3rd week so wich condition?